# Injecting key_events in one button click in android.

Tags: android, key-events

In my application i want to do the same functionality happening while invoking a set of KEY_EVENT with in a button click. Is that possible.

Comment: Yes, you can handle key-events within your `Activity` or pass them to a `View` like a `Button` and handle them there. Can you please explain your goals furthermore and provide us with some things you have tried so far. Thanks

Comment: For example i want to print my name "Parvathy Kamalone" by pressing one button placed in activity by invoking all the key events like KEYCODE_P, KEYCODE_A ,KEYCODE_R etc.